# Parameterfree heir-coheir relation in stable theories (II)

Tags: solution-verification, model-theory, alternative-proof

Let $M\models T$, a stable theory. Let $a,b\in U\succ M$.

> A. Are the following equivalent? (For a comparison, cfr. [this other question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948753/parameterfree-heir-coheir-relation-in-stable-theories).)

1. $\varphi(M,b)\neq\varnothing$ for every $\varphi(x,z)\in L(M)$ such that $\varphi(a,b)$
2. $\psi(M,M,b)\neq\varnothing$ for every $\psi(x,y,z)\in L$ and $m\in M$ such that $\varphi(a,m,b)$

If I am not mistaken, 2$\Rightarrow$1 is a rephrasing of Exercise 8.3.8 of Tent-Ziegler (*weak heir $\Rightarrow$ heir*). In the appendix, they give a hint.

> B.  But, would the following more direct strategy also work? (I hope it is not too sketchy/delusional - in the case, I can expand/delete respectively).

Let $L\big[{\rm ext}(x,y)\big]$ be the language $L$ expanded with a symbol for every formula $\psi(x,y,z)\in L$ where the variables $x,y,z$ are fixed. Let $M\big[{\rm ext}(a,b)\big]$ be the expansion of $M$ that interprets $\psi(x,y,z)$ with $\psi(a,M,b)$.

We also need the intermediate expansions $L\big[{\rm ext}(y)\big]$ and $M\big[{\rm ext}(b)\big]$ which we defined similarly.

Step I. Assume $M$ is saturated and prove $2\Rightarrow1$ as follows. Use stability to conclude that $M\big[{\rm ext}(b)\big]$ is saturated in the language $L\big[{\rm ext}(y)\big]$. Let $m\in M$ be such that $\psi(a,m,b)$. To prove 1 we show that $\psi(m',m,b)$ for some $m'\in M$.

Let $p(y)={\rm tp}(m)$ in the language  $L\big[{\rm ext}(y)\big]$. By 2 the type $\{\psi(x,y,b)\}\cup p(y)$ is finitely satisfied in $M$. Hence, by saturation, there is are $m',m''\in M$ such that $\psi(m',m'',b)$ and $m''\equiv m$ in the expansion $L\big[{\rm ext}(y)\big]$.
As $M\big[{\rm ext}(b)\big]$ is homogeneous, there is an $f\in{\rm Aut}\big(M\big[{\rm ext}(b)\big]\big)$ such that $f(m'')=m$. Hence  $\psi(f(m'),m,b)$ as required.

Step II. Prove that in a stable theory, for every $M,a,b$ and every sufficiently large saturated model $N$ such that $M\big[{\rm ext}(a,b)\big]\equiv N\big[{\rm ext}(a,b)\big]$, where the symbol of elementary equivalence refers to the language $L\big[{\rm ext}(x,y)\big]$. Note that both 1 and 2 hold for $M$ iff they hold for $N$.

Comment: In Step I, how do you use homogeneity to easily obtain 1?

Comment: I edited *Step I* of the proof sketch to add more details.

Comment: Thanks for adding more details! Now I don't understand the step "by saturation, we can require $m''\equiv m$ in the expansion".

Comment: Further expanded.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't understand why $\{\psi(x,y,b)\}\cup p(y)$ is finitely satisfied in $M$. To get consistency, it seems you need to know that $p(y)$ does not imply $\lnot \exists x\, \psi(x,y,b)\}$.  But this is equivalent to saying that $M\models \exists x\, \psi(x,m,b)$, which is exactly what you're trying to prove... I think there's maybe a confusion here arising from treating these expansions too casually. Note that if we expand both $M$ and the monster model by your new relations in the natural way, $M$ may no longer be an elementary substructure of the monster!

Comment: Pick θ(y) ∈ p. Then ψ(a,m,b) ∧ θ(m) holds. By 2, there are m',m'' ∈ M such that ψ(m',m'',b) ∧ θ(m''). (In any case, thank for the time spent of this.)

Comment: Since $\theta$ is a formula in the expanded language, you can't apply (2) to it.

Comment: Yes I can! It contains the external parameter $b$, just like $\psi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117346/discussion-between-alex-kruckman-and-primo-petri).